# Problem in loading web page when using polyval, polyfit using numpy

Tags: python, django, numpy, centos, django-wsgi

I am using django1.3. in CentOS5. My python version is 2.6 and using the numpy 1.6.1.
I used in `views.py` a function which calculate the regression line.

A sample code:

```
from numpy import *
....
def test_func(request):
   n=50
   t=linspace(-5,5,n)
   #parameters
   a=0.8; b=-4
   x=polyval([a,b],t)
   #add some noise
   xn=x+randn(n)

   #Linear regressison -polyfit - polyfit can be used other orders polys
   (ar,br)=polyfit(t,xn,1)
   xr=polyval([ar,br],t)

 return ...
```

In the browser if I call the page, it cannot load. But it works fine in windows with the default development server which comes with the `django`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: <concentrates hard>... No, my psychic vision isn't working, I can't seem to see your error messages. Would you mind posting them here?

Comment: If this is server dependent it is not a numpy problem.

Comment: polyval, polyfit works with the python command line in the server computer(in this case centos). But when I tried to load in the webpage, the browser just continues to load the page, nothing else happen. Its not complaning any error, so I don't know what to do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `WSGIApplicationGroup` directive to your `httpd.conf` file.

```
<Directory /www/django/apache>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently investigating a similar issue (Gentoo, Python 2.7, Numpy 1.6.0), and it would seem that *only in wsgi*, the following numpy code ends up blocking :

```
eps = np.finfo(float).eps
```

The [help page for finfo](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html) says:

> For developers of NumPy: do not instantiate this at the module level. The initial calculation of these parameters is expensive and negatively impacts import times. These objects are cached, so calling finfo() repeatedly inside your functions is not a problem.

Not sure what's going on here, but downgrading to Numpy 1.5.1 seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: When you say WSGI do you mean Apache/mod_wsgi? If so, read http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API and try overriding the interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the issues. I also thought that this might be a reason so far but I didn't find anything mentioning about it. I tried my problem without using these functions polyval or polyfit which is a temporary solution perhaps.